# access rails app without using http

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to interact with a rails(3) app without going though the http layer? I have some processes running locally on the server, which i'd like to be able to make some changes. Similar to what you can do in the rails console, but in a non-interactive way. I just would just call some ruby scripts to update some records in the database, rather than type them myself in the rails console.

Comment: please be more specific, you can use rake for tasks, etc. but it depends what concretely you need to do

Comment: `rails runner 'puts "this is executed in the context of your app"'`?

Comment: There's also Resque and DelayedJob if you need to run background jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Write these scripts you are talking about, connect via ssh and run them from the bash?!^^

ssh is the secure shell, sth. like telnet but encrytped with ssl if you are no linux user you may dont know about it...

Ahh damn and when you write thes scrips you must do this to get your applications environment:

```
require 'config/environment.rb'
```

After requireing the environment file you cann acces all your Models with the script!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP wanted to know how to write and run the scripts, not how to SSH to the server.

Comment: just the require 'config/environment.rb' is enough thanks! Thats all I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to update a bunch of records in the DB, you don't need complete Rails installation. You can write a script and establish connection manually. Something like:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_record'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :adapter => "sqlite3",  :database => "users.db"
  set_table_name "users"
end

User.create(:name => 'a user', :email => 'user@example.com')
```

And call this from cron the way you want.

Comment: interesting, is this going to be a lot faster than what was mentioned in the first answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a custom rake task.

Place a file, say, task.rake in your lib/tasks directory.  In that file, define a task:

```
task :mytask => :environment do
    #code here
end
```

and call it from the command line:

```
> rake mytask
```